# How to extract only part of the JSON and de-serialize it in .netcore

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I have .net core application , where an API is called through HTTPClient.
The response for that API in JSON format is as follows:

```
{
    "ID": 25,
    "Customer": "CustomerName",
    "total": 100,    
    "details": [
        {
            "ItemId": "Item1",
            "ItemName": "Name1",
            "Price": "10"           
        },
        {
           "ItemId": "Item2",
            "ItemName": "Name2",
            "Price": "50"  
        },
        {
            "ItemId": "Item3",
            "ItemName": "Name3",
            "Price": "40"  
        }
    ]
}
```

I get this response from -- > `var response = client.GetAsync(ApiPath).Result;`

Now from the response variable I need details only for details like :

```
{   
        {
            "ItemId": "Item1",            
            "Price": "10"           
        },
        {
           "ItemId": "Item2",           
            "Price": "50"  
        },
        {
            "ItemId": "Item3",            
            "Price": "40"  
        }    
}
```

I have a DTO class like this :

```
 public class ItemDetails
    {
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Can anyone help in extracting the details according to the DTO class from the main variable "`response`".

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json?  If Newtonsoft, this is probably what you're looking for: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenWithLinq.htm

Comment: I'm using Newtonsoft. I was able to convert the response into JObject , but couldn't extract data of type ItemDetails.--> ItemDetails[] itemDetails = o.SelectToken("Items").Select(s => (ItemDetails)s).ToArray(); . This gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you are using [newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)

```
var token = JObject.Parse(response);//load
var detailsToken = token.SelectToken("details");//select
var itemDetails = detailsToken.ToObject<ItemDetails[]>(); //cast to array
```

Only the properties that exist on `ItemDetails` will be mapped

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize the response into an object and take whatever you like from it.

Use the built-in JSON library in `.net-core` as following

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
```

then make a Response classes to contain the Response values

```
public class ResponseObject
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("total")]
        public int Total { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("details")]
        public ItemDetails[] Details { get; set; }
    }

public class ItemDetails
    {
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
```

finally, deserialize and extract whatever you like as following

```
var o = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseObject>(response);
ItemDetails[] itemDetails= o.Details;
```